# How to get fragment coordinate in fragment shader in Metal?

Tags: ios, iphone, gpu, metal

This minimal Metal shader pair renders a simple interpolated gradient onto the screen (when provided with a vertex quad/triangle) based on the vertices' color attributes:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>

using namespace metal;

typedef struct {
    float4 position [[position]];
    float4  color;
} vertex_t;

vertex vertex_t vertex_function(const device vertex_t *vertices [[buffer(0)]], uint vid [[vertex_id]]) {
    return vertices[vid];
}

fragment half4 fragment_function(vertex_t interpolated [[stage_in]]) {
    return half4(interpolated.color);
}
```

…with the following vertices:

```
{
  // x,    y,   z,   w,   r,   g,   b,   a    
     1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,

     1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
     1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0
}
```

So far so good. It renders the well-known gradient triangle/quad.
The one you find in pretty much every single GPU HelloWorld tutorial.

---

I however need to have a fragment shader that instead of taking the interpolated  vertex color computes a color based on the fragments position on screen.
It receives a screen-filling quad of vertices and then uses only the fragment shader to calculate the actual colors.

From my understanding the position of a vertex is a `float4` with the first three elements being the 3d vector and the 4th element set to `1.0`.

So—I thought—it should be easy to modify the above to have it simply reinterpret the vertex' position as a color in the fragment shader, right?

```
#include <metal_stdlib>

using namespace metal;

typedef struct {
    float4 position [[position]];
} vertex_t;

vertex vertex_t vertex_function(const device vertex_t *vertices [[buffer(0)]], uint vid [[vertex_id]]) {
    return vertices[vid];
}

fragment half4 fragment_function(vertex_t interpolated [[stage_in]]) {
    float4 color = interpolated.position;
    color += 1.0; // move from range -1..1 to 0..2
    color *= 0.5; // scale from range 0..2 to 0..1
    return half4(color);
}
```

…with the following vertices:

```
{
  // x,    y,   z,   w,
     1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0,

     1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
     1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
}
```

I was quite surprised however to find a uniformly colored (yellow) screen being rendered, instead of a gradient going from `red=0.0` to `red=1.0` in x-axis and `green=0.0` to `green=1.0` in x-axis:

([expected render output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXk3A.jpg) vs. [actual render output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/st110.jpg))

The `interpolated.position` appears to be yielding the same value for each fragment.

What am I doing wrong here?

<sub>Ps: (While this dummy fragment logic could have easily been accomplished using vertex interpolation, my actual fragment logic cannot.)</sub>

Comment: position.w is only 1 when you aren't using a perspective "camera". .xyz is divided by .w by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The interpolated.position appears to be yielding the same value for
>   each fragment.

No, the values are just very large. The variable with the [[position]] qualifier, in the fragment shader, is in pixel coordinates. Divide by the render target dimensions, and you'll see what you want, except for having to invert the green value, because Metal's convention is to define the upper-left as the origin for this, not the bottom-left.

Comment: Oh, that explains it then. That was the missing part. Works now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @jessy: How would you get the render target dimensions dynamically? Do you pass them into the shader as a uniform? Are they available as a constant?

Comment: +1 I'd also like to know if there's a way to get the size of the render target other than by passing it in as a uniform. @jessy